# How to detect the group of characters in a string using RegEx?

Tags: regex

I have strings as follows :

```
M0122PD12XS1, 
M1213234NW, 
M1213234EFA1.
```

I need to read the last two/three characters in each string as follows. There will be at most one number after characters at the end regardless of numbers after it. 
I need to read the last characters as follows :

```
M0122PD12XS1 => XS
M1213234NW => NW
M1213234EFA1=> EFA
```

I used the regex string as follows but it only read the last two/three characters when there are no other numbers next.

```
Regex string : ".{0,0}\D*$".
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `\D{2,3}(?=\d*$)` or `[A-Za-z]{2,3}(?=\d*$)`?

Comment: [A-Z]{2,3}((?=\d\b)|(?=\r)|(?=\.)|(?=\b))

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you need:

```regex
.*[0-9]([a-zA-Z]+)
```

look [here](https://regex101.com/r/08Q0YJ/1) for testing and [here](https://jex.im/regulex/#!cmd=export&flags=&re=.*%5B0-9%5D(%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%2B)) for visualization.

Comment: I only need to pull last two or three characters. No need of number after characters . For example M123123XS1, I need XS only.

Comment: @PCG I typed the string you provided in and it worked as you asked.. The regex doesn't even match numbers in the end only letters stated by ```[a-zA-Z]```

Answer (score 1):

Good question, we would be using the punctuation or space on the right side of our desired two or three letters with a simple expression:

```
[0-9]([A-Z]{2,3})([0-9])?[,.\s]
```

and on its left we would use the existing number as a left boundary.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Ixbos/1)

```js
const regex = /[0-9]([A-Z]{2,3})([0-9])?[,.\s]/gm;
const str = `M0122PD12XS1, 
M1213234NW, 
M1213234EFA1.
M0122PD12XS1
M1213234NW
M1213234EFA1
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: The question implies there are no punctuation symbols at the end, and I suspect those `,` and `.` are just "formatting" punctuation marks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

`([A-Z]{2,})(?:[,.\s\d]+)?$`

If no punctation required in the line ends, just

`([A-Z]{2,})(?:[\d]+)?$`

Where `[A-Z]{2,}` are 2 and more letters, `[\d]+)?` are optional numbers in the end of string.

Comment: Why obfuscate so much? `(?:[\d]+)?` = `\d*`.

Comment: I only need the last two/three characters. But your script pulls numbers with last characters.

Comment: @PCG: no, there is `?:` at the beggining of second group, so result is just `[A-Z]{2,}`. You can try it, nothing easier :-) There is nothing like `take just the last one group` in regexes, you need to define it other way. If you don't want the rest (number), just add `?:` to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

[A-Z]{2,3}((?=\d\b)|(?=\r)|(?=.)|(?=\b))

Finds 2 or 3 Alpha Characters [A-Z]{2,3}

Up to, but not including (?=) either

- Single Digit, followed by a word boundary (?=\d\b)
- Return Character (?=\r)
- Period Character (?=\.)
- Word Boundary (?=\b)